# Splitting Time Blocks By Time Window on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query I am running on BigQuery where I want to be able to combine rows of by specific time frames and average the value of other rows.

For example, given this `table`:

```
timestamp                  |  value
___________________
2018-08-09 17:25:22 UTC    |  40000
2018-08-09 17:55:22 UTC    |  10000
2018-08-09 18:25:22 UTC    |  20000
2018-08-09 18:55:22 UTC    |  20000
2018-08-10 12:55:22 UTC    |  5000
```

I want to be able to query it so I can display the results as by hour
so, the 2018-08-09 17:00:00 row would be the combination of the two time blocks and has the average value of `25000` (40000+10000/2).

How would I be able to write the query in BigQuery to group it by either hour blocks or even day blocks.

I want the result of my query to be like this:

```
timestamp                     | value
_____________________________________
2018-08-09 17:00:00 UTC       |  25000
2018-08-09 18:00:00 UTC       |  20000
2018-08-10 12:00:00 UTC       |  5000
```

BigQuery SQL has an AVG function that can averaged over a timespan, but not sure how to aggregate them first before averaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR) ts, AVG(value) AS value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR)
```

you can test, play with it using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 17:25:22 UTC' ts, 40000 value UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-09 17:55:22 UTC', 10000 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-09 18:25:22 UTC', 20000 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-09 18:55:22 UTC', 20000 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-10 12:55:22 UTC', 5000 
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR) ts, AVG(value) AS value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR)
```

with result

```
Row     ts                          value    
1       2018-08-09 17:00:00 UTC     25000.0  
2       2018-08-09 18:00:00 UTC     20000.0  
3       2018-08-10 12:00:00 UTC     5000.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this has solved my issue!